# PHP convert double quoted string to single quoted literal string

Tags: php, string

Is there a way to convert the double quoted string `"<b>foo</b>"` to the single quoted string `'<b>foo</b>'`. Please note that I cannot use `<?php strip_tags("<b>foo</b>")?>`, I need to tags to be present.

EDIT: I should have asked a question, I would like to styling to be removed, I don't wish foo to be boldened - just for `<b>foo</b>` to be echo'd to the screen.

**Solution found:** For anyone interested: `htmlspecialchars` does the job.

Cheers,
Kay

Comment: Sorry but your edit just lost me there. What do you mean by styling, and why does it have to do with single or double quotes?

Comment: missleading title: This has nothing to do with the string interpolation, but is instead a PHP - HTML related issue.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I misunderstood, would a simple string substitution work?

```
str_replace('"', "'", '"<b>foo</b>"'); //'<b>foo</b>'
```